# <polymer-dragula> doesn't work in Polymer#2.0

Tags: polymer, dragula

```
<polymer-dragula>
    <div class="row-holder">
        <div class="column">
            <p>item-1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>item-2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>item-3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>item-4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>item-5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</polymer-dragula>
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For drag and drop i will recommend you

> [polymer-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/polymer-sortablejs)

its also available

> "polymer-sortablejs": "bmwalters/polymer-sortablejs#2.0-preview"
>   easy to handle and impliment

Comment: Good alternate suggestion, working for me in Polymer#2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to read the information mentioned in the [github](https://github.com/ergo/polymer-dragula).

> Information: Before [bevacqua/dragula#470](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/pull/470) gets merged into dragula this
>   element might not work correctly inside Shadow DOM.